# How to position relative element on top of another relative element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know this might not be possible the way I said it. This is the result I'm aiming for: [link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKiNy.jpg)

The header container should be containing the video and the height should not exceed the video height since other stuff need to appear in the same flow. The h1 and p should be positioned in the middle of the header. The h1 and p element must too be relative since they need to be relative to each other.

I've tried adding another z-index to the text with relative positioning, but can't seem to make it work. I'd love any help I can get! :)

Html:

```
<header>
    <video class="header-video" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="Images and videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    <!--If video can't be played display text-->
    Sorry! Your browser can't display this video. 
</video>
<h1>Say my name</h1>
<div class="thin-line"></div>
<p>I need a sign or a signal. I've overthought everything I can think of into symbol I need the coat and your jacket And the remnants of your cigarette packet</p>
```

Css:

```
/* Images and videos
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.header-video {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* Header
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10vh;
}

header h1 {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 7em;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

header p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 22%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 30vw;
    margin: 2vh auto 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}

/* Lines
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.thin-line {
    display: block;
    height: 0.1em;
    width: 60vw;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: check this website https://www.airbnb.com/ i think it is very helpful to you. you can check code in inspect element.

Comment: Why do the p and h1 need to be relative? Just put them in a div, absolute position that at top: 50%, left: 50% with translate(-50%, -50%) to center it.

Comment: @DanishKhan It's what I'm trying to achieve. But I couldn't find what I was looking for exactly. :(

Comment: @Rudi That was mostly because I don't want them to overflow the header on smaller screens. What does the translat do?

Comment: If you position it with left: 50%, top: 50% it won't be centered, the top left point of your div will be centered. By using translate you actually center the div + its content.
It's best to try it out to see what I mean. It's hard to make clear with words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the outer div CSS style position relative. And make the inner one absolute. For center the inner element use CSS style "position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate3D(-50%, -50%, 0);".

For full height screen use CSS style "Height: 100vh;". That means Viewport Height for Full Screen Div.

https://jsfiddle.net/sadika/x624o8cn/3/

CSS:

```
<style>

body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.hero-bg{
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.hero-bg{
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/400/nature/); 
}
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="hero-bg">
      <div class="hero"> 
            <h1 style="font-size:36px;margin: 15px;">Say my Name</h1> 
            <hr />
            <p style="font-size:18px;ma">
            I need a sign or a signal. I've overthought everything I can think of into symbol I need the coat and your jacket And the remnants of your cigarette packet
            </p> 
      </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

Comment: I settled for a solution similar to this. Thanks for your answer!